# How to use pfx certificate in postman?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

There is a way to import a **.pfx** certificate in postman?
I need to send a user certificate for testing my API.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer Postman didn't support **.PFX** files.  Ref: 
[Feature Request: Support for PFX](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2494)

However you can extract cert and private key from the .PFX file using openSSL and configure those in Postman.

**Extract key:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pfxfile.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes
```

**Extract cert:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pfxfile.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

Comment: All the downloads for openssl seem really shady. Luckily it looks like openssl comes installed on the git bash so you can just open that up and run the above command.

Comment: PFX is now supported as of version 7

Comment: This proved extremely useful when I was able to submit .pfx files via Postman but not via python's `requests`. Used these instructions to decompose into .pem files and submitted those instead - worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Postman Canary Update has support for PFX Files now. You may use that build instead. [image]

Comment: I add my PFX file, but when clicking 'Add' it tells me I need a host.

Comment: @Alex.A Of course you need to fill in the host, certificates are 'per domain'